# Emit a lot of messages vs join a lot of rooms

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, notifications

Socket.io offers first-class support to address specific recipients by using [rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms)

I'm creating a webapp where the server passes notifications to the user via Socket.io. It is a marketplace. Users may favourite/buy/sell articles and will therefore be notified from the server when something changes.

Now I've got to make the choices whether a user joins a room for every article he is interested upon login or whether I emit a message for every user individually when something changes.

**What is more efficient? Is there a best practice? Am I taking on this problem from the wrong perspective?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rooms are only a construct on the server for keeping track of lists of sockets.  When you broadcast to a room, all the socket.io code does is loop through the list of sockets and send a message individually to each one.

So, in either of your cases, a message is being sent individually to each socket - same for both.  Use rooms if the mechanism for keeping track of groups of sockets and being able to easily send a message to each one is useful and works for your purpose.

If you have some reason to want to use your own data structures for keeping track of lists of sockets, then that's fine too and it won't cost any more to loop through it and send a message to each one as long as you have an efficient scheme for finding which sockets you want to send the message to.